# Cannot insert number in two-dimensional vector

Tags: c++, std

I have the following declaration of a two-dimensional vector:

```
vector< vector<int> > tableT;
```

I try to insert a number through:

```
tableT[0].push_back(1);
```

This results in a fatal error.

I use all the relevant libraries, and `using namespace std`

Comment: You're probably accessing `tableT` out of bounds. But you should post an [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Before you can do : `tableT[0].push_back(1);` you need to :

```
tableT.push_back( vector<int>() );
```

Example:

```
tableT.push_back( vector<int>() );
tableT[0].push_back(1);
```

this will give you:

```
{
   {1}
}
```

if you push_back again to `tableT[0]`:

```
tableT[0].push_back(1);
```

you will have:

```
{
   {1, 1}
}
```

if you want to add one more row, you need to `push_back` again to `tableT`:

```
tableT.push_back( vector<int>() );
```

and then:

```
tableT[1].push_back(3); // or tableT.back().push_back(3);
```

and now you have:

```
{
   {1, 1},
   {3}
}
```

Comment: @DimChtz- it's working. Why do I have to do it?

Comment: @sara8 Let me edit it and explain

Comment: @sara8: Because there is no such thing as a 2D vector. What you have is a vector of vectors. If you don't have any vectors in your vector of vectors then you can't push back to them :P i.e. `tableT[0]` doesn't exist yet, just like how `tableT[0][0]` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @sara8 No need to edit, BarryTheHatchet explained it :)

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet- in case I want to insert 2 elements to the second vector in the vector (I want that the output will be {{1},{5,3}}) I should do the following-                                                                         tableT.push_back( vector<int>() );                        tableT[0].push_back(1);                                             tableT[1].push_back(5);                                        tableT[1].push_back(3);?

Comment: @sara8 I added an example

Comment: @ DimChtz- thanks for the great example!!!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: If you already know the dimensions of the 2D `vector`,

```
vector< vector<int> > tableT(number_of_rows, vector<int>(number_of_columns));
```

will build a rectangular matrix an allocate all the `vector`s and storage you need. For example,

```
vector< vector<int> > tableT(24, vector<int>(120000));
```

will make something similar to

```
int tableT[24][120000];
```

but in reality is one `vector` of 24 `vector`s and 24 `vector`s of 120000 `int`s. `vector`s of `vector`s have performance concerns, but none OP likely needs worrying about.